# Parse signup doesn't authenticate the user correctly

Tags: android, authentication, parse-platform

I encountered a very strange error when signing up a user using android 6 on a specific device.
The signup process works perfectly and the user is registered on Parse database. The code checks and if `ParseUser.getCurrentUser() != null` then the app sends the user to the main page and this all works till here. 
 However, I noticed that user is not able to send any requests to the server and it all rejects in the main activity and user can't even logout. The error I receive when logging out is:

```
com.parse.ParseRequest $ParseRequestException: This user is not allowed to add a field to _User. You can change this setting in the Data Browser.
```

It seems like the authenticated user object is not matched with the original user's token on server and that is why this user get ACL errors.
I am using Parse default signup and login functions and this has happened only on one device using android 6 so far. Any guess on what could cause this issue and how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
ParseACL roleACL = new ParseACL();
roleACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
```

Add these lines after the user `Parse.initialize()` function. It allow user to create column in the table from mobile. Make sure the user is logged in otherwise it gives error.

Comment: How does this exactly help? Your just creating a role and even not assigning it to a user or anything.
You mean I just add this after users signed up?